# Define VisualStudio color theme by solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, themes

is it possible to configurate Visual Studio so that the color theme depends on the current C#-Solution.

Why I need this? If have two similar solutions on disk (an experimental one and a productive one).
When both solutions are in use at same time then it can happen that I'm confused and write my experimental code into the productive one.

In order to avoid mistakes it would be nice if the one visual studio window theme is white and the other black.

If that is not supported, is there any similar feature?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You can use this addons which let you change the color by solution https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wumpf.SolutionColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no such feature or plugin.
But, maybe this can help you

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.RenameVisualStudioWindowTitle

http://erwinmayer.com/labs/visual-studio-2010-extension-rename-visual-studio-window-title

I'm using it to view, in VS title, TFS branch that I'm working on (prod or dev).

Comment: Thank you. That solution is OK. The negative thing is that both plugins does not change the title in undocked windwos.